# Iterators.filter vs for-each

Tags: java, guava

Maybe it's obvious or dumb question, so I'm sorry in advance.

Lets's suppose I've got two following ways of iterating through collections with simple conditions:

## 1

```
Predicate<SomeObject> pred1 = new Predicate<SomeObject> () {... some condition_1 ...};
Predicate<SomeObject> pred2 = new Predicate<SomeObject> () {... some condition_2 ...};
Iterator<SomeObject> newIterator = Iterators.filter(iterator, pred1);
... do something like Sets.newHashSet(newIterator) ...
newIterator = Iterators.filter(iterator, pred2);
... do something like Sets.newHashSet(newIterator) ...
```

## 2

```
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
 SomeObject someObject = iterator.next();
   if (condition_1) {
    ...do something like set.add(someObject)...
   } else if (condition_2) {
    ...do something like set.add(someObject)...
   }
}
```

Am I right, that #2 is more faster than #1 ?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: isn't it is too obvious to tell that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imperative version will be faster, but how much is very difficult to determine.  In my tests, once hot, both versions returned in under 1.1 microseconds. The imperative version method ran faster than 5.15 micros in 95% of cases (1,000,000 randomly executed runs) while the FluentIterable version ran faster than 6.6 micros for 95% of its cases.

Guava can be extremely quick especially if predicates and functions can be defined statically.

In the below example notice the usage of predicate composition and FluentIterable.

FluentIterable is especially attractive as usages can be replaced with Java 8 streams with minimal modification.

```
public static class SomeObject {

    private final String someString;

    public SomeObject(final String someString) {
        this.someString = someString;
    }

    public String getSomeString() {
        return this.someString;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.someString;
    }
}

public static final Predicate<SomeObject> CONTAINS_A_FILTER = new Predicate<GuavaExample.SomeObject>() {

    @Override
    public boolean apply(final SomeObject someObject) {

        return someObject.getSomeString()
            .contains("A");
    }
};

public static final Predicate<SomeObject> CONTAINS_B_FILTER = new Predicate<GuavaExample.SomeObject>() {

    @Override
    public boolean apply(final SomeObject someObject) {

        return someObject.getSomeString()
            .contains("B");
    }
};

public static final Predicate<SomeObject> CONTAINS_A_AND_B_FILTER = Predicates.and(CONTAINS_A_FILTER,
        CONTAINS_B_FILTER);

public static final Predicate<SomeObject> CONTAINS_A_OR_B_FILTER = Predicates.or(CONTAINS_A_FILTER,
        CONTAINS_B_FILTER);

public static void main(final String... args) {

   final List<SomeObject> someObjects = ImmutableList.of(new SomeObject("A"), new SomeObject("AB"),
            new SomeObject("B"), new SomeObject("C"));

    final Set<SomeObject> containsAandB = FluentIterable.from(someObjects)
            .filter(CONTAINS_A_AND_B_FILTER)
            .toSet();

    // prints [AB]
    System.out.println(containsAandB);

    final Set<SomeObject> containsAOrB = FluentIterable.from(someObjects)
            .filter(CONTAINS_A_OR_B_FILTER)
            .toSet();

    // prints [A, AB, B]
    System.out.println(containsAOrB);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think #2 may be faster.

Example #1 filters the collection twice. Each filtering counts as an iteration. Therefore, you are most likely spending more time by filtering them. I might be very wrong on this as I've seen a question on why iterating through sorted collections is faster than unsorted collections, but hopefully someone will elaborate.

Example #2, however, iterates over it once.

Don't take my word for it, but I'm pretty sure I'm on the right page here.